# Text node cannot be a child of a <view> react-native

Tags: react-native

I am struggling badly to resolve this warning while working on a react-native application. The app is a todo-list and its is giving me a warning that goes like: A text node cannot be a child of a <View>.

Here's my code:

```js
class Task extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.item}>
        <View style={styles.itemLeft}>
          <View style={styles.square}></View>
          <View style={styles.itemText}>
            <Text>{this.props.text}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.circular}></View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

This warning crashes all of the application all at once due to extreme memory leak, and I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: Can you show where you use the Task component? And is there a reason that you are using a class component rather than a functional component

Answer (score 0):

In React Native, the  component should be used directly inside the parent component, without any enclosing View.

```
class Task extends React.Component{
   constructor(props) {
   super(props);
 }

render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <View style={styles.itemLeft}>
      <View style={styles.square}></View>
      <Text style={styles.itemText}>{this.props.text}</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.circular}></View>
  </View>
 );
 }
}
```

In this modified code, I removed the unnecessary View around the Text component ({this.props.text}). The  component is now a direct child of the parent View.

Comment: Do you mean that Text component should not get into a parent View component unless there's a sibling component for it?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. In React Native, the Text component is a special component used for displaying text, and it should not be wrapped in a View unless there are other components alongside it as siblings